# PostgreSQL pgdb driver raises "can't rollback" exception

Tags: python, exception, postgresql, transactions

for some reason I'm experiencing the Operational Error with "can't rollback" message when I attempt to roll back my transaction in the following context:

```
try:
    cursors[instance].execute("lock revision, app, timeout IN SHARE MODE")
    cursors[instance].execute("insert into app (type, active, active_revision, contents, z) values ('session', true, %s, %s, 0) returning id", (cRevision, sessionId))
    sAppId = cursors[instance].fetchone()[0]
    cursors[instance].execute("insert into revision (app_id, type) values (%s, 'active')", (sAppId,))
    cursors[instance].execute("insert into timeout (app_id, last_seen) values (%s, now())", (sAppId,))
    connections[instance].commit()
except pgdb.DatabaseError, e:
    connections[instance].rollback()
    return "{status: 'error', errno:4, errmsg: \"%s\"}"%(str(e).replace('\"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r'))
```

The driver in use is PGDB.

What is fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you exclude the lock statement?

This is what's happening inside pgdb.py:

```
def rollback(self):
    """Roll back to the start of any pending transaction."""
    if self._cnx:
        if self._tnx:
            self._tnx = False
            try:
                self._cnx.source().execute("ROLLBACK")
            except Exception:
                raise OperationalError("can't rollback")
    else:
        raise OperationalError("connection has been closed")
```

So I suggest you replace your `connections[instance].rollback()` call with:

```
connections[instance]._tnx = False
connections[instance]._cnx.source().execute("ROLLBACK")
```

to see if that gives you a more informative error message (the except clause inside pgdb is greedy).

Also: check the Postgresql log, it will have probably logged the reason!

Comment: Hmm, sorry; you're right, it shouldn't matter. Do you have the same problems if you exclude the `lock` statement?

Comment: I haven't tried; however, I seriously doubt that the logic of my application allows to operate on tables without locking them first. Would you like me to test anyway?

Comment: See my suggestions added to my answer;

Comment: @David Parunakian: a single underscore is an indication that the variable is for private use but you should be able to alter it without trouble. A double underscore does the same (but with some name mangling). Python does *not* intrinsically have the concept of private variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the wrong place. What does the PostgreSQL log say about what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you start the transaction? I do see a COMMIT but don't see a BEGIN or START TRANSACTION.

Comment: iirc the dbapi2 spec (which pgdb / pygresql implements) implies transactions in the scope of the connection object by default

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'm a SQL-guy, that's why I expect plain SQL.